# Providing uniqueness using a many to many relationship with SQL for use with Java

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am a bit perplexed by a problem and wonder if I am missing something simple.

I have three tables:

```
create table A (id serial primary key, name char(50));
create table B (id serial primary key, name char(50));
create table c (A int references A(id), B int references b(id));
```

and I ensure that the A & B relationship is not repeated using:

```
create index unique_a_b_in_c on c (A,B);
```

I am then using hibernate to reverse engineer these files into Java objects.

So far so good, but now what I want to do is ensure that each instance of A has a unique combination of B records. (e.g. if I have 2 records in B  -  B1 and B2, I can therefore only have four possible values for my A records, which would be: no records, a B1 record, a B2 record, or a B1 and a B2 record.)

My best attempt at this so far is to create a unique hashcode in A which is based on the type B records belonging to that a record, and then overriding equals to function to check  the contents of A's collection of B records. If the objects are equal, I will update the A record, but if the A record is new, I can save it.

Clearly this is a heavy process for equals, and as the size of B gets larger, the processing time when checking for the matches is getting huge.

My current thinking is to abandon any attempt to provide this kind of uniqueness, and allow duplicates, although they do not make sense in the context of my problem, since A is really defined by the combination of B records from which it is composed.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how they might go about resolving this ?

Many Thanks !

Comment: So essentially, you are trying to make the set of relationships unique? If A1 relates to (B1 and B2), then A2 can't have (B1 and B2), but A2 can have (B1), (B2), or (none).

Comment: Yes, exactly. Of course when you have B1 to B10 there are a lot more combinations !
EDIT:
Actually, to be picky, in your scenario, if A1 relates to (B1 and B2), then if A2 attempts to relate to (B1 and B2) I really want to recognise A2 as actually being another instance of A1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have your group of "B"'s defined, it should be a simple matter to build a SELECT statement to check to see if it's already defined as an "A".

```
SELECT A, count(*) as rows from c where B IN ( 'B1', 'B2' ... ) group by A
```

If the count(*) = the number of elements in your IN clause, then you've found an A that matches B. This statement should run relatively quickly, especially if B is indexed.

It will slow down as c grows, however. You could try adding

```
HAVING count(*) = 2 (or whatever your count of the number of rows of B is)
```

But since HAVING is usually done by the optimizers after the initial query, it probably won't speed it up, but it will give you *one* row back if it matches, and zero if not.